# How to query specific values in sequel pro?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, sequelpro

I'm using sequel pro to run some queries on a large database that I have. I am quite new to this so please excuse if my question is stupid or obvious.

I have data from app users who have played a specific game (which in our database has value 32. They can play a number of times. I select COUNT(gamescore.Score) to find the number of times they played the game and a new score will be recorded for each time they play. Now I want to know what their 3rd game score in time was, if they played multiple times.

I have attached an image for better explanation. The person with UserID 18211 has played game "32" a number of times and their scores are shown in the first column. I want to know what is the score when they played the game for the third time. So by looking at the table, I know that this score is 109 the third time they played which was on 2016-09-09. But I have to do this for many users so I can't look at them all manually.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gamescore.UserID, COUNT(gamescore.Score), gamescore.GameId
FROM gamescore
WHERE gamescore.GameID = "32"
GROUP BY gamescore.UserID
```

I'm unsure of how to modify the query to get score of the 3rd time they played...  Can anyone help?

Sample data: [image]

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "3rd game score"  .. update your question adding  proper data sample and the expected  result  please

Comment: @scaisEdge I have added in some extra info and an example image.. hope it's clearer now what I am after.

Comment: Google 'sql (quota OR window) query (third or nth OR n-th)'. PS Please avoid images, for tables you can cut & paste into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

for the 3rd  game score you can use   a  limit on an ordered  by select  eg:

```
   select t.UserID , t.Score, t.dateCreated, t.GameId from (
          select UserID, Score, dateCreated, GameId 
          from gamescore
          WHERE GameID = '32'
          and UserId = 18211
          order by  dateCreated  limit 3 
          ) t 
    order by dateCreated limit 1 desc
```

but for get these result for all the UserId  you should iterate server side on your UserId list and repeat the select for each user

Comment: I am getting this error when I run this: [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asc
) order by dateCreated limit 1 desc' at line 6

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui   answer  updated   (missing t for table name )

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui   .. i have updateb the answer  with a sligthly modified  version   hope this work

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui Iteration is *not* how to do this kind of query.